# Create new numpy array-scalar of flexible dtype

Tags: python, numpy

I have a working solution to my problem, but when trying different things I was astounded there wasn't a better solution that I could find. It all boils down to creating a single flexible dtype value for comparing and inserting into an array.

I have an RGB 24-bit image (so 8-bits for each R, G, and B) image array. It turns out for some actions it is best to use it as a 3D array with HxWx3 other times it is best to use it as a structured array with the dtype([('R',uint8),('G',uint8),('B',uint8)]). One example is when trying to relabel the image colors so that every unique color is given a different value. I do this with the following code:

```
# Given im as an array of HxWx3, dtype=uint8
from numpy import dtype, uint8, unique, insert, searchsorted
rgb_dtype = dtype([('R',uint8),('G',uint8),('B',uint8)]))
im = im.view(dtype=rgb_dtype).squeeze() # need squeeze to remove the third dim
values = unique(im)
if tuple(values[0]) != (0, 0, 0):
    values = insert(values, 0, 0) # value 0 needs to always be (0, 0, 0)
labels = searchsorted(values, im)
```

This works beautifully, however I am tried to make the `if` statement look nicer and just couldn't find a way. So lets look at the comparison first:

```
>>> values[0]
(0, 0, 0)
>>> values[0] == 0
False
>>> values[0] == (0, 0, 0)
False
>>> values[0] == array([0, 0, 0])
False
>>> values[0] == array([uint8(0), uint8(0), uint8(0)]).view(dtype=rgb_dtype)[0]
True
>>> values[0] == zeros((), dtype=rgb_dtype)
True
```

But what if you wanted something besides (0, 0, 0) or (1, 1, 1) and something that was not ridiculous looking? It seems like there should be an easier way to construct this, like `rgb_dtype.create((0,0,0))`.

Next with the insert statement, you need to insert 0 for `(0, 0, 0)`. For other values this really does not work, for example inserting `(1, 2, 3)` actually inserts `(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)`.

So in the end, is there a nicer way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make `insert()` work for your case doing (note that instead of `0` it is used `[0]`):

```
values = insert(values, [0], (1,2,3))
```

giving (for example):

```
array([(0, 1, 3), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 4), ..., (255, 255, 251), (255, 255, 253), (255, 255, 255)],
       dtype=[('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
```

Regarding another way to do your `if`, you can do this:

```
str(values[0]) == str((0,0,0))
```

or, perhaps more robust:

```
eval(str(values[0])) == eval(str(0,0,0))
```

Comment: Oddly enough today insert(values, 0, (1,2,3)) works fine too. I am trying to reproduce the failure...

Comment: It looks like insert(values, 0, (1,2,3)) works with NumPy v1.7.0 and earlier but starting in NumPy v1.7.1 you need to do [0] instead like suggested here. Starting with the NumPy v1.8.0 docs this new feature is mentioned (says new in v1.8.0 but I can see that it actually was introduced in v1.7.1) and they give a special note about the difference between 0 and [0]. Thanks!

Comment: For the comparison part, I am keeping with tuple(values[0]) == (0,0,0). Thanks for the suggestions though!